# Cannot boot into Linux, low graphics error, cannot boot into terminal

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

The title is a little confusing but this is the problem. I deleted my Ubuntu partition and didn't bother to fix the bootloader so I enter the grub console when ever is boot my laptop up. I reinstall Ubuntu and it was successful. When I rebooted it, it goes into low graphics. I followed the directions on the low graphics but terminal would load. Right now I'm reinstalling Ubuntu but putting the bootloader (or whatever it's called) on the same partition as the OS. If this still doesn't work, can someone help me solve my boot into terminal problem?

Answer (score 0):

Steps to install Ubuntu is really simple.
After you run the ubuntu installer:
Create a partition in the installation process and make it mount to /boot size maybe 1GB Another partition for the root / or as you like your schema to be.

If you have more than one hard drive (actual hard drive not partition) then you need to make sure that it is on the top of boot order from the BIOS setup, and make sure that it is the hard drive you chose to install the boot loader.

Another important point is: remove the CD/USB that you used to install ubuntu after the installation.

Comment: Uh, ive got installed fine but also I got the problem fixed too. Now my problem is that I cant boot into windows (I dual booted... obviously). Instead of the Ubuntu windows boot manger and all the other options, I get a black windows with the usual ubuntu purple as a border. I dont know if this is a graphics issue or what though. Any comments on this?

Comment: No this is not a graphic problem. You can not boot into windows is a different matter. Do you have UEFI boot or legacy?

Comment: UEFI boot I believe

Comment: If you have installed Ubuntu on legacy boot, then the only way to boot Windows is to switch back to UEFI. Ok try this: go to bios setup and switch to UEFI. and see if windows starts (if windows asks for recovery there will be a chance that windows will overwrite the boot sector which causes ubuntu to be not bootable). There are 2 ways to install ubuntu, the easy way in my opinion is to install ubuntu in legacy mode, and whenever you want to start windows you will have to switch back to UEFI. The other way is a long process of installing ubuntu in UEFI boot.